# Excel, using a second index match if first is empty

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I was wondering if theres an easy way to setup a formula that is an index match one a sheet of data, and then if there was no match, look somewhere else.

I have new results which I want to look up from, then if not I have historical results to look up from. I dont want to combine the data as I dont want the historical numbers to change any averages in the new results.

I could use two columns each with a different index match and then some IF, OR statements but I'd like to know if theres a way of doing it all in one forumla.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH will return an error where a matching value is not found. This can be used to switch to an alternative match attempt, eg:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet1!B:B,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(C1,Sheet2!B:B,0)))
```

Comment: That is so obvious, can't believe I missed that! Thanks for the help.